# Compiling two apps in two folders with Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am dealing with 2 package.json and from my one Docker file am trying to run a sequence of commands in each folder. I am trying to wrap my head around WORKDIR as its not behaving the way I expect.

app structure

```
package.json
   client/
      package.json
Dockerfile
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM ...

RUN npm install -g yarn

# run yarn install and build inside the client folder
WORKDIR ./client
RUN yarn install
RUN yarn build

# go back to the parent directory and run yarn install then CMD
WORKDIR ../
COPY . .
RUN yarn install
EXPOSE 6000
CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

What is the right way to deal work with WORKDIR in this example?
I keep getting `error Couldn't find a package.json file in "/client"` which makes me beleive I'm not using WORKDIR correctly.

Comment: Your `WORKDIR` is probably fine, but in the example you show, you don't `COPY` anything in before you `RUN` commands that depend on _e.g._ the `package.json`.

Comment: ahhh I see, thank you David!

Answer (score 1):

`yarn build` requires a `package.json` under current directory, so need to assure there is one under the folder `client`.

In fact when you do `WORKDIR ../` & `COPY . .`, the working directory already changed, not in the folder `client`, but the parent of the `client`.

```
# run yarn install and build inside the client folder
WORKDIR ./client
COPY . .
RUN yarn install
RUN yarn build
```

Meanwhile, assure your package.json has a `build command`:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node ./app.js",
    "build": "ls"
},
```

Comment: Thank you atline!